# On the double meaning of evaluation

Tags: british-english, subcontinental-english, australian-english

I know that evaluation can refer to both the process and the result, but when you say something is an evaluation of another thing, like fact is evaluation of claim (forgive the choppiness, the sentence is being used for something that requires not necessarily proper English), would you assume:

a)  A fact is used to evaluate a claim

or

b) A fact is the result of evaluating a claim?

I am particularly interested in non-American English answers. Thanks.

Comment: A fact may be used to evaluate a claim. A fact is not the result of evaluating a claim. I don't think that depends on your version of English (or your language in general). The statement "fact is evaluation of claim" makes no sense to me whatsoever.

Comment: You evaluate something and end up with an evaluation. Similarly, you paint something, and end up with it painted.

Answer (score -1):

I can give you an answer from the perspective of a German native speaker using English on an everyday basis for work across Europe.

For me your sentence

> Fact is evaluation of claim

sounds like a shorter form or

> Facts are the result of a process of evaluating a claim for truthfulness

However, note that my area of work is education and project management, and in both areas "evaluation" is used as a *terminus technicus* for a procedure to systematically assess the quality of something (usually a teach-and-learn process or project implementation). This specific use of the word may have shaped my attitude towards it.

On the other hand, a large percentage of my media ingestion has been US-related for quite a time now, so I am definitely not free of US-American tropes. But I would not see where this would affect my understanding of your sentence.